# How to handle the same answer for multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, data-request

Many inquiries for specific datasets seem to be in regards to datasets lost to linkrot. I've answered a couple simply by finding them in the wayback machine; so my question is: do I continue to answer each one by searching for them? or is there a way to point them to a definitive answer?
on that note, perhaps we could create a question "How Can I Find Missing Data" (that could be worded much better), and then answer it with the wayback machine, then direct users there?

EDIT:
Here's the question/answer I created:
[Searching for Open Data Dataset That is No Longer Online](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4749/searching-for-open-data-dataset-that-is-no-longer-online)

Comment: Whatever the consensus here will turn out to be: Go ahead and create that question, [answer it yourself](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), collect the reputation, and wear it proudly :)

Comment: @PatrickHoefler ok i'll do it. i know you edit regularly, but please keep an eye out and help me with the wording...i think i did a pretty poor job wording this question here ;)

Comment: I'm sure you'll do just fine :)